# Ripple effect framelayout round button

Tags: android, button, effect, ripple

I have in my layout this kind of display:

```
<FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/beatiful_yellow"
            android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/downloadButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@null"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_60px"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                android:minWidth="0dp"
                android:drawableTint="@color/colorAccent"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
```

with roundbutton.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#eeffffff" />
    <corners android:radius="110dp"/>
</shape>
```

It allows me to have a round button with a centered icon in it.
But now, I would like to have a Ripple effect when the button is clicked.

I tried many solutions, such as this one [Tutorial for rounded layouts](http://michaelevans.org/blog/2015/05/07/android-ripples-with-rounded-corners/) but none worked. Is there a trick to have an acceptable effect when the button is clicked? Ripple would be nice, but another one could do the trick I guess...

Thanks :)

===========================================

EDIT:

Thanks to the comment of Rockney, It is now working with the following code:

```
            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/beatiful_yellow"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_file_download_black_60px"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            />
```

Comment: You might want to look into the FloatingActionButton. It is a round-button with a centered icon. You can customise it.

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I needed. Thank you :)